# URL routing in codeigniter

Tags: .htaccess, codeigniter, url-routing, codeigniter-url

I have been using .htaccess files to redirect some of my renamed controllers/actions. Say for example...

```
RewriteRule ^top/index/?(.*)?$ /index.php/home/index/$1 [L]
```

Can I use the config/routes.php file for the same purpose or is it that routes.php can only be used for URL rewriting or is is that it recognises the controllers/actions which actually exist?

Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got my answer. It works both ways.